# Derived Classes with different value types

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm facing kind of a design dilemma.
How would you solve this?

I receive a packet via UDP as a byte[]. I then parse this array into a packet object. This packet has several attributes (e.g. username, password, timestamp).

So I wrote an attribute parser, that parses the byte[] into an attribute object.
The attribute has different properties such as AttributeId and Value.
The problem is: these *value properties* can have different *types*(e.g. username and password are of type ascii string, timestamp is of type long etc..)

At some point these attributes get compared to entries in a database, for authentication purposes, only at this point is it important to know exactly what type it is.

I thought about deriving from an abstract Attribute class, but since the value types are different, this wouldn't help much.

How do you normally handle this type of situation?

**EDIT:**
The sender of the message is not under my control and follows [RFC 2865](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2865).
Example of what a message might look like.

- *1st Byte* - Message Type Code
- *Next Byte* - Client Id
- *Next 2 Bytes* - Message Length (byte count)
- *Next 16 Bytes* - Pseudo random token
- *Rest Bytes* - Request attributes

**These attributes all folow this format.**

- *1st byte* - Attribtue type (this defines what the type of the value will be)
- *Next Byte* - Attribute length (byte count)
- *Rest byte* - Value

Comment: Do you control both sender and receiver? What do you actually receive? Can you qualify *attribute*? Of course you always receive bytes, but what do these bytes represent? Can you give an example of what you get. If you control both sides, you can use a class object known to all *players*. Serialize the class object (XmlSerializer, JSON) and deserialize on the receiving end, so you're *attributes* are all strong typed.

Comment: Of course you always get a byte array when dealing with over-the-wire transmissions. But I mean: I literally get a byte array. Each byte represents a part of the data. I do not control both sides, so serialization is not possible. Please see my edit for further clarification.

Comment: Also, @Jimi can you clarify what you mean by "qualify attribute" ?

Comment: You already did, finally mentioning what this is all about. Your question title, *Derived Classes with different value types*, should probably be *Hot to manually handle RADIUS authorization*. See here: [RADIUS Authentication, Authorization, and Accounting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nps/ias-radius-authentication-and-accounting) for general information on the protocol and here for a ready-to-use library: [Radius.NET - GitHUb](https://github.com/frontporch/Radius.NET). Note that the System uses this auth protocol in different situations, see if an existing one fits.

Comment: I am not looking a RADIUS library nor am I looking for information about the RADIUS protocol. I believe the RFC is much more complete, than that blog post. I'm asking a specific question about how you would solve a Situation where derived classes can have different value types. I gave the sitaution I am in as an example. But I would like to hear how people solve these types of issues from a design perspective.

Comment: That's why I linked that GitHub repo. It's not necessarily meant to be used as it is, but because you can study how it's implemented. See [Radius/Attributes](https://github.com/frontporch/Radius.NET/blob/master/Radius/Attributes/RadiusAttribute.cs). *How do you normally handle this type of situation?*: you convert the data to a strongly typed .Net object, mapping each *attribute* to a type.

Comment: I don't understand your dilemma. A dilemma is a choice between two equally bad (or good) options.